solving the dual optimization Problem of SVR using quadprog
Could someone please take a look at my code and verify if the H matrix, w, and b are correct? I'm working on a project and want to ensure these components are accurate. Your help would be greatly appreciated
% Goal is to train an SVR model that predicts the values of "rain" 

 % DATASVRNEW is the data containing both the input vectors and the target variable 
 % The column temperature contains the data for average temperature over a period of time in some locations 
 % The column pressure contains the data for average pressure over a period of time 
 % The column Humidity contains the average humidity over a period of time
 
 % Partitioning the data 
 X_train = DATASVRNEW(:, 1:3); % Data for the input vectors 
 Y_train = DATASVRNEW(:, 4); % Data for the target variable to be predicted
 
 N = size(X_train, 1); % Number of samples in the training set
 



% Defining the model parameters 
 C = 5; % C is the regularization parameter for the model 
 Epsilon = 0.01; % Epsilon is the error tolerance level for the model 

     % Shuffling the data 
 shuffled_indices = randperm(N); 
 X_train = X_train(shuffled_indices, :); 
 Y_train = Y_train(shuffled_indices); 

 % Introducing the kernel Function (Polynomial) for computing the inner products of the input vectors 
 degree = 3; % Degree of the polynomial kernel 
 coef0 = 1; % Coefficient term in the polynomial kernel 
   
Kernel_F = @(X1, X2) (X1 * X2' + coef0).^degree;
K = Kernel_F(X_train, X_train);
   

 % Setting up the optimization problem 
 H = [K -K; -K K]; % Matrix for the quadratic part of the optimization problem 
 H = double(H); 

   
f = Epsilon * ones(2 * N, 1) + [-Y_train; Y_train]; % Linear part of the optimization problem
f = double(f);

   
 Aeq = [eye(N) -eye(N)]; % Equality constraint matrix 
 Aeq = double(Aeq);
 
 Beq = zeros(N, 1); % Right-hand side of the equality constraint 
 Beq = double(Beq); 

  Ub = C * ones(2 * N, 1); % Upper bound for the decision variables 
 Ub = double(Ub);  

 lb = zeros(2 * N, 1); % Lower bound for the decision variables 
 lb = double(lb); 

 % Solving the optimization problem 
 options = optimset('Algorithm', 'interior-point-convex'); 
 [result, fval] = quadprog(H, f, [], [], Aeq, Beq, lb, Ub, [], options);
 
 % Extracting the result of the dual variables 
 alpha_pos = result(1:N); 
 alpha_neg = result(N+1:end); 

 % Display results 
 disp('Dual Variables (alpha_pos):'); 
 disp(alpha_pos); 
 disp('Dual Variables (alpha_neg):'); 
 disp(alpha_neg); 

 % Check if all dual variables are the same 
   
 if all(alpha_pos == alpha_pos(1)) && all(alpha_neg == alpha_neg(1)) 
    disp('Warning: All dual variables have the same value.');
end

   
 % Calculating weights and bias 
 alpha = alpha_pos - alpha_neg; % Combine positive and negative dual variables 
 w = alpha' * X_train; % Weight vector calculation
 
 % Calculate bias term 
 b = mean(Y_train - X_train * w'); % Bias term 

 % Testing the model 
 X_test = X_train; % Here we use the training data as the test data 
 Y_pred = X_test * w' + b; % Model predictions
 
 % Scatter plot of true vs predicted value s
 figure; 
 scatter(Y_train, Y_pred); 
 xlabel('True Values'); 
 ylabel('Predicted Values'); 
 title('SVR Predictions vs True Values'); 
 grid on; 

Could you please review the following points in my code:
H matrix: Is my formulation of the H matrix correct for this problem?
w calculation: Am I correctly computing the weight vector w?
b calculation: Is my bias term ,b calculated correctly?
Any feedback or suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.
